# Static properties syntax

Tags: c#, syntax, properties

I'm going through [The C# Player’s Guide](https://csharpplayersguide.com) book and doing tasks. There is this one that asks to create a class for RGB color and **static properties** for common colors (white, black, yellow, green, blue, purple, orange). [Here](https://csharpplayersguide.com/solutions/5th-edition/the-color) is the proposed solution.

For example, orange:

```
public static Color Orange { get; } = new Color(255,  165,    0);
```

I'm seeing this syntax for the first time, i.e. class name before property name (Color Orange), and constructor call after curly brackets. Where can I read more about this? I don't even know what to Google.

Comment: It's simply initialising a property where it's declared. It's just like you would declare a variable and assign a value to it.

Comment: Take a look at [Properties in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties)

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces part are called "auto properties". The're just syntax sugars for getters and setters. You can read more about it on [DotNet Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

The constructor part is just a initialization to the property. It's the same as if you initialized it from the constructor. But, since it's a static property without a public setter, that's the only way to initialize it.

That said, this small code is almost the same that if I write the below:

```cs
private static Color _orange = new Color(255, 165, 0);

public static GetOrange() {
  return _orange;
}
```